# access pdf element in iframe

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

I have attached a pdf to html trough iframe.
Now I try to access elements inside the dom with javaScript.
However normal way to access iframes does not seem to be valid..
Tried various variations. for instance:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myFrame');
var win = ifrm.contentWindow;  
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
var form = doc.getElementById('findInput');
form.value = 'my string'
```

So the id="findInput" is the search field in the pdf

Comment: A PDF is not HTML, so you can't access it like HTML.

Comment: yes i can, when it is not inside an iframe. Just look with inspect element and what is inside the DOM. It is simple html.